# Microsoft Unity 3.0 DI with Lazy<List<IFoo>> does not work

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have following configuration in my code with which a view is configured as a IWorkflowModule:

```
 dependencyContainer.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, StartView>();
```

I would like to get all these IWorkflowModule implementation as constructor parameters of another class. This class is instantiated after the registration of the modules.

```
  public WorkflowConfigReader(Lazy<List<IWorkflowModule>>
                                        availableWorkflowModules)
  {
      this.availableWorkflowModules = availableWorkflowModules;
  }
```

The parameter of the constructor is Lazy because I will use the modules some time later on and want to be sure that they are registred before. I also need them as a list to get all the modules.

Unfortuanatly, I get an empty list if I do it this way. I am not sure but I guess Unity does not support dependency injection for a IEnumerable which is not staticly configured. Is this correct? Are there any solutions for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Unity what you want when a `List<IWorkflowModule>` is requested.  So you could do something like:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// Default registration if required
container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, StartView>();

// IEnumerable Registration 
container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, StartView>("WorkflowConfigReaderItem1");
container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, EndView>("WorkflowConfigReaderItem2");
container.RegisterType<List<IWorkflowModule>>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        return c.ResolveAll<IWorkflowModule>().ToList();
    }));
```

Unity does know how to resolve arrays so if you were to use an array of `IWorkflowModule` then you wouldn't have to register an InjectionFactory:

```
public WorkflowConfigReader(Lazy<IWorkflowModule[]>
                        availableWorkflowModules)
{
    this.availableWorkflowModules = availableWorkflowModules;
}

// Default registration if required
container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, StartView>();

container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, StartView>("WorkflowConfigReaderItem1");
container.RegisterType<IWorkflowModule, EndView>("WorkflowConfigReaderItem2");

var configReader = container.Resolve<WorkflowConfigReader>();
```